# autolayout in swift after copying my view controller to a new scene

Tags: swift, autolayout

I have my first view controller which looks fine. After a click on a label the user will go to the next "scene".

In this "scene" I copied my first view controller scene, as it looks almost identical, I then took the time to set every constraints on the new scene until it looked the same as my first entry scene.

It says there is no "auto layout" issues. If I update all my frames in Xcode, it also looks great. HOWEVER, when I run my app, the only thing that is on my next scene is the background, nothing else? not even a single label...

Anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Do one thing copy the main view and put it as subview in the new controller scene view and set it's layout, equal width, equal height, center horizontally, center vertically and vola it's done.

Comment: That exactly what I did @rPavi.

Which is why this is weird because all the other labels are where they should be, HOWEVER this label comes up when you click on another label. So I started to think it could be something with my code for the click on the button, but again its the same code I used on the other view. So why would it be different. (but I have a feeling that it must be something in my function of the label action, that I need somehow to address my labels x,y location after the click. Maybe?)

Comment: If you can post the code It will be more helpful and y you are using label to navigate why not button and segue just out of curiosity ;)